# MongoDB in the cloud hosting, benefits

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting, dotcloud, joyent

Im still fighting with mongoDB and I think this war will end is not soon.

My database has a size of 15.95 Gb;

- Objects - 9963099;
- Data Size - 4.65g;
- Storage Size - 7.21g;
- Extents - 269;
- Indexes - 19;
- Index Size - 1.68g;

Powered by:

```
Quad Xeon E3-1220 4 × 3.10 GHz / 8Gb
```

For me to pay dearly for a dedicated server.
On VPS 6GB memory, database is not imported.

Migrate to the cloud service?

https://www.dotcloud.com/pricing.html

I try to pick up the rate but there max 4Gb memory mongoDB (USD 552.96/month o_0), I even import your base can not, not enough memory.
Or something I do not know about cloud services (no experience with)?
Cloud services are not available to a large database mongoDB?

```
2 x Xeon 3.60 GHz, 2M Cache, 800 MHz FSB / 12Gb
```

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/pe1850/en/UG/p1295aa.htm

Will work my database on that server?

This is of course all the fun and get the experience in the development, but already beginning to pall ... =]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "On a standard hosting with 6GB memory database is not imported.". Is the performance too low with less memory?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Oh, I meant VPS 6Gb. I could not import the database because it does not have enough memory.

Comment: Hm, are you trying to import the whole database into memory? I can't remember MongoDB being very memory hungry unless the load is extremely high.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I'm trying to just do the import database on the server. `mongorestore --db mydatabase /home/mydatabase/` But surgery can not end because they do not have enough memory.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have an issue with a db of this size. We were running a mongodb instance on Dotcloud with 100's of GB of data. It may just be because Dotcloud only allow 10GB of HDD space by default per service.

We were able to backup and restore that instance on 4GB of RAM - albeit that it took several hours

I would suggest you email them directly support@dotcloud.com to get help increasing the HDD allocation of your instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using ObjectRocket which is a MOngoDB as a service. For a 20Gb database the price is $149 per month - http://www.objectrocket.com/pricing